# C - Code after switch in for loop ignored

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, switch-statement

I have this bit of code in C:

```
for(int y = 1; y <= array_size; y++){          //outer loop starts here
    for(int x = 1; x <= array_size; x++){      //inner loop starts here

            switch(array[x][y]){
            case 1: dosomething;
            case 2: dosomething;
            case 3: dosomething;
            }

            makestuff;                        //this line is ignored
    }                                         //inner loop ends here
    outerloop;                                //outer loop - everything works fine      
}                                             //outer loop ends here
```

and as you can see if I use switch, the code after it is just ignored despite it still being in the inner loop.

But if I rewrite the code like this:

```
for(int y = 1; y <= array_size; y++){          //outer loop starts here
    for(int x = 1; x <= array_size; x++){      //inner loop starts here

        if(array[x][y]==1)
            dosomething;
        else if(array[x][y]==2)
            dosomething;
        else if(array[x][y]==3)
            dosomething;

            makestuff;                        //works
    }                                         //inner loop ends here
    outerloop;                                //outer loop - everything works fine              
}                                             //outer loop ends here
```

it works as I expected. It would not a problem if I used the second method but I would just like to know why the first method does not work.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Please edit your question with code which compiles.

Comment: Difficult to tell but what happens if you put `break` statements after each `dosomething`

Comment: If those case blocks end with `break` and don't contain `continue` or jumps, they should be semantically equivalent to the if-else chain at the bottom. https://ideone.com/daqyzN

Comment: Please post an [mcve]. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are making assertions that are not backed up by the (incomplete) code shown.

Comment: On here, you should try to make the example code in your question into an mcve -- http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: `int x = 1; x <= array_size; x++` seems wrong.  Try `int x = 0; x < array_size; x++`

Comment: `#define dosomething  default:continue;}switch(0){case 0:break` would explain the observed behavior for the switch code fragment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what are you doing and how did you tested, but this simple code works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define array_size 2
int main() {
    int array[array_size][array_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array_size; j++) {
            array[i][j] = i;
        }
    }

    for (int y = 1; y <= array_size; y++) {
        for(int x = 1; x <= array_size; x++) {

            switch(array[x][y]) {
                case 1: printf("One\n"); break;
                case 2: printf("Two\n"); break;
                case 3: printf("Three\n"); break;
                default: printf("Nothing\n"); break;
            }

            printf("I'm not ignored\n");
        }
    }
    printf("END\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
One
I'm not ignored
Nothing
I'm not ignored
Nothing
I'm not ignored
Nothing
I'm not ignored
END
```